# Typescript: type narrowing not working for `in` when key is stored in a variable

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

Consider this simple [snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8AoKUA+UDeyU4EYC4oA7AVwFtcIAnAbmxQF9t0sccBjQ0i6uthuogBmJIu2ABLAPZEoQgIwAKAIaEYASkzYJQqIoDkufVAmzlm1jioRgJKmYDah-QF0+UJimu37UACwATHRMwqLi0rJCASpqFtjsMgDOwFAA1hAgCFDO7jp66ZmmUOZabN52jgVu2J5Q5b6BwUA). I'm also pasting it here:

```
type A =
  | {
      b: number;
    }
  | {
      c: number;
    };

function f1(a: A) {
  if ('b' in a) {
    return a['b']; // No problem!
  }
  return 42;
}

function f2(a: A) {
  const key = 'b';
  if (key in a) {
    return a[key];  // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'
  }
  return 42;
}
```

Why doesn't the type of `a` get narrowed to `{b: number}` in `f2`? (as it is for `f1`)

Comment: It's just as your title says - it doesn't work when you use a variable. Apparently, it adds a lot of complexity to the analysis that the compiler has to to, hence why the TS guys didn't implement this.

Comment: It works if you are explicit about the `key` type. For example, `const key = 'b' as keyof A;`.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger `keyof A` is `never` because there are no keys common to all the constituents of the `A` union.  Writing `const key = 'b' as keyof A` is equivalent to writing `const key = 'b' as never` which is explicit but unsound and usually not advisable.  The type inferred by `const key = 'b'` is just `'b'`.  If you are explicit about that, as in `const key: 'b' = 'b'` or maybe `const key = 'b' as 'b', you have the same as shown above.  The problem is not explicitness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is essentially the same issue as [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); type narrowing from control flow analysis only happens for properties that are directly literals like `"b"` and not for arbitrary expressions whose types are [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types).  Issue #10530 talks about narrowing via property access... like `a.b` or `a["b"]`, which *does* cause `a` to be narrowed, vs `a[key]`, which *does not*.

As you've noticed, this also happens with the `in` operator type guard (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256)), where `"b" in a` narrows the type of `a`, but `key in a` does not.  This is not explicitly mentioned in #10530 (which pre-dates the `in` type guard) but I don't think there's another existing issue specifically about this.

According to [microsoft/TypeScript#10565](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10565), an initial attempt to address the issue in #10530, adding type guard functionality for arbitrary expressions of literal types significantly worsens the compiler performance.  Maybe performing extra analysis for all `x in y` checks would be less expensive than performing extra analysis for all `y[x]` property accesses, but at least so far nobody has cared much.

You could always open your own issue about it in GitHub (many issues end up being duplicates, and I'm not 100% sure this wouldn't just be considered a duplicate of #10530, or that there isn't some other issue this duplicates), but practically speaking it's probably not going to change anytime soon.

---

If you want a workaround for the case where you can't just replace `key` with a string literal, you could write your own [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) called `hasProp(obj, prop)`.  The implementation would just return `prop in obj`, but its type signature explicitly says that a `true` result should cause `obj` to be narrowed to just those union members with a key of type `prop`:

```
function hasProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: T, prop: K
): obj is Extract<T, { [P in K]?: any }> {
    return prop in obj;
}
```

and then in your function, replace `key in a` with `hasProp(a, key)`:

```
function f3(a: A) {
    const key = 'b';
    if (hasProp(a, key)) {
        return a[key];  // okay
    }
    return 42;
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8BYAUFNUA+UDeL36gCMAuKAOwFcBbQiAJwG490BfZtLXVAtAY1Mo16TbmhYiUAMwplewAJYB7MlEkBGABQBDUjACUOdlHmSoGgOSFzxlVoNceaOhGAU6tgNqXzAXQZQAegCoADlFKDA6RUIAGwgqAEIjNlEoZ1d3KAAWACYRFKkZOSUVSRztXXsjXmUAZ2AoAGsIEAQobxF8EzNm1vlbKtT8dLdPXr80IKgABSjIOlB2qygAE0UIWvJFBogAD3l6qGUoUEh2mHNkoxHM3PyUQtkFY4ALLVrZxTAAHgAVKD2wAgZBWm2iACsIHIADRQADSAN2QJBm0+81AcJaAD4NEYIaRfrDIl9SHCUHpSBDjJsAKJIuhaOR-WHYKAeaY2eE+AD8pC0ZFaLCxhlSNxUxLAnIh92Qj2Kx0kAGYKrBBvgamRDr02h0jN0NG8PnNtLDeno1Y4xVAtB5xv5AsFFI0tK0rqKXKNsnkUAVkEA)

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what way does the workaround improve over `as keyof A`? It certainly looks more complex. For instance, `const key = 'asdf';` has the same behavior when the more complex type is used.

Comment: After working with the example more closely I see that there are benefits to using the more complex function/type, but only when `key` is `const`. If the variable is not constant like `var`, `let`, or a function parameter, then the complex type doesn't seem to make a difference, but I'd be happy to hear otherwise.

Comment: `keyof A` is `never`, so unless you want the compiler to interpret `a[key]` as `never` (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/PmLO4N)), just about anything is an improvement.  I'd really recommend forgetting about `as keyof A` as a possible way to deal with this.

Comment: When you write `var key = "b"` or `let key = "b"` the compiler widens the type of `key` to `string`.  When you have a key of type `string`, the compiler cannot use any obvious method to narrow the type of the object you're indexing into. For example, if `k` and `k1` are both of type `string`, the type system sees no difference between `if (k in obj) return obj[k]` and `if (k in obj) return obj[k1]` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#34867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34867)).  If you annotate like `let key: "b" = "b";` then the user-defined type guard works again.

Comment: Understood. Coercing the type into `never` is not a good idea. I was mostly trying to understand what benefits the more complex solution provides, in terms of compile time errors. The additional info about `a[key] = never` makes things more clear. I was expecting the more complex type to prevent me from making mistakes in this context. Like only allow me to use a property value that exists in at least one of the types (e.g. `const key = 'asdf'` gets interpreted as an error since `asdf` isn't a valid key for `A`.)

Comment: @jcalz could you explain the question mark in `obj is Extract<T, { [P in K]?: any }> `? Removing it doesn't seem to make any difference. What is it doing there?

Comment: @LGenzelis the question mark only makes a difference if the union type you're discriminating has an optional property.  If `A` were, for example, `{b?: number} | {c: number}` then you'd see that `Extract<A, {[ P in "b" ]: any}>` evaluates to `never`, while `Extract<A, {[ P in "b"]?: any}>` evaluates to `{b?: number}`.  Whether that difference is important to you. and which behavior is preferable if so, is up to you of course.

Comment: @jcalz to confirm, `obj is Extract<T, { [P in K]?: any }>` is an equality statement right? And `Extract<T, { [P in K]?: any }>` is saying... take this key out of the object... the value can be anything. If you cannot take the key from the object, then it'll become  `obj is false` then it all becomes false?

Comment: Not at all. `obj is …` is a [type predicate](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), and [the `Extract` utility type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) filters unions. So it means "if this function returns `true`, then `obj` can be narrowed from the full union `T` to just those members with a key of type `K`, otherwise it can be narrowed from the full union `T` to just those members without a key of type `K`". You might want to read the TS docs or make your own post if you run into trouble. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You need [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like this:

```js
function isin<T>(key: PropertyKey, obj: T): key is keyof T {
  return key in obj;
}
```

TypeScript doesn't narrow the type of a key stored in a variable, apparently for a performance reason.

For an alternative approach and the detailed reason for why TypeScript doesn't do it, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618261/13651701

Comment: Unlike the other version  this works is the type of key is not narrowed down at compile tmie. e.g. `key : 'a' | 'b'`

Answer (score 1):

In older typescript version 3.6.3 both existing answers above did not work for me. I am stuck in an older version because of my target environment. Please see below my working version:

```js
/**
 * Type guard function to check if a property exists in an object.
 * 
 * @template T - The type of the object. Must extend object.
 * 
 * @param {PropertyKey} key - The property key to check.
 * @param {T} obj - The object in which to check for the property.
 * 
 * @returns {boolean} - True if the property exists in the object, false otherwise.
 * 
 * If true, the TypeScript type of `key` is narrowed to be a keyof `T`, 
 * indicating it exists as a property within the object `T`.
 */
export function is_in<T extends Object>(
    key: PropertyKey, obj: T
): key is keyof T {
    return key in obj;
}
```