# Why doesn't a type narrowing check of a class property not work when assigned to a variable (aliased conditions)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards, type-narrowing, typescript4.0

How can I narrow the type of property of a class in an aliased conditional expressions?

**Short**: In a class method I want to do a type narrowing check such as `this._end === null && this._head === null`, but I want to first assign the result of this check to a variable before using it in a type narrowing `if` clause. It's not working as expected.

**Not short**: Let's say we have a *Queue* class:

```
class Queue {
  private _length: number = 0;
  private _head: Node | null = null;
  private _end: Node | null = null;

  public enqueue(node: Node): boolean {
    this._length += 1;

    const isQueueEmpty = this._end === null;
    if (isQueueEmpty) {
      this._head = node;
      this._end = node;
      return true;
    }

    this._end.setLink(node); // TypeScript doesn't understand that this._end passed the null check 
                             // in the if statement and writes that this._end can be null. 
    this._end = node;
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you write a check in the *enqueue* function directly in the **if** condition, then TypeScript understands that *this._end* is not **null**:

```
public enqueue(node: Node): boolean {
  this._length += 1;

  if (this._end === null) {
    this._head = node;
    this._end = node;
    return true;
  }

  this._end.setLink(node); // Now TypeScript understand that this._end passed the null check
  this._end = node;
  return true;
}
```

But the code turns out to be less descriptive.

Moreover, in general, I need to say that both properties of the class passed the **null** check. Specifically: *this._head* and *this._end*.

I wrote the following method:

```
type QueuePointerKeys = '_head' | '_end';

private _isQueueEmpty(): this is this & { [K in QueuePointerKeys]: null } {
  return this._end === null;
}
```

And it doesn't work. If you put it in the *enqueue* method, then:

```
public enqueue(node: Node): boolean {
  this._length += 1;

  if (this._isQueueEmpty()) {
    this._head = node;     // TypeScript writes that a variable of type null cannot be assigned the type Node
    this._end = node;      // TypeScript writes that a variable of type null cannot be assigned the type Node
    return true;
  }

  this._end.setLink(node); // TypeScript doesn't understand that this._end passed the null check
                           // in the if statement and writes that this._end can be null.
  this._end = node;
  return true;
}
```

How do I use a class method such as `_isQueueEmpty` for type narrowing? That works similarly to `this._end === null && this._head === null` used directly as the condition of the **if** statement?

Comment: RE your use of the word "typeguard":  https://youtu.be/dTRKCXC0JFg   (note my username ;)

Comment: I added links to relevant GitHub Issues to my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: type narrowing not working for \`in\` when key is stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616994/typescript-type-narrowing-not-working-for-in-when-key-is-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Control Flow Analysis of Aliased Conditions and Discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) was only recently added, and it has limitations, including:

> Narrowing through indirect references occurs only when the conditional expression or discriminant property access is declared in a const variable declaration with no type annotation, and the reference being narrowed is a const variable, a readonly property, or a parameter for which there are no assignments in the function body.

Since `this._end` is not a readonly property, it's not going to work for you. I confirmed that this is your problem by assigning `this._end` to a local const variable, and then using it for the condition as well as the `setLink` call:

```js
interface Node {
  setLink(node: Node): void
}

class Queue {
  private _length: number = 0;
  private _head: Node | null = null;
  private _end: Node | null = null;

  public enqueue(node: Node): boolean {
    this._length += 1;

    const end = this._end
    const isQueueEmpty = end === null;

    if (isQueueEmpty) {
      this._head = node;
      this._end = node;
      return true;
    }

    end.setLink(node);
    this._end = node;
    return true;
  }

}
```

In fact, there is an open issue addressing your specific case:  [Control flow analysis of aliased conditions is not able to narrow object properties #46412](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46412), as well as [Allow non-readonly properties to be used in aliased conditional expressions #44972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44972).

Let's hope they can find solutions for these soonish