# TypeScript Discriminated Union with Optional Discriminant

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've created a discriminated union that's later used to type props coming into a React component. A pared down sample case of what I've created looks like this:

```
type Client = {
    kind?: 'client',
    fn: (updatedIds: string[]) => void
};

type Server = {
    kind: 'server',
    fn: (selectionListId: string) => void
};

type Thing = Client | Server;
```

Note that the discriminant, `kind`, is optional in one code path, but is defaulted when it is destructured in the component definition:

```
function MyComponent(props: Thing) {
    const {
        kind = 'client',        
        fn
    } = props;

    if (kind === 'client') {
        props.fn(['hey']);
        // also an error:
        // fn(['hey'])
    } else {
        props.fn('hi')
        // also an error:
        // fn('hey')
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is what's going on with this conditional. I understand that the type checker is having trouble properly narrowing the type of `Thing`, since the default value is separate from the type definition. The oddest part is that in both branches of the conditional it insists that `fn` is of type `(arg0: string[] & string) => void` and I don't understand why the type checker is trying to intersect the parameters here.

I would have expected it to be unhappy about non-exhaustiveness of the branches (i.e. not checking the `undefined` branch) or just an error on the `else` branch where the `'server'` and `undefined` branches don't line up. But even trying to rearrange the code to be more explicit about each branch doesn't seem to make any impact.

Perhaps because the compiler simply can't narrow the types so tries an intersection so it doesn't matter which path--if the signatures are compatible then it's fine to call the function, otherwise you basically end up with a `never` (since `string[] & string` is an impossible type)?

I understand that there are a variety of ways I can resolve this via [user-defined type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), but I'm trying to get a better grasp on what's going on here internally *and* to find something a bit more elegant.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwgO2FAvFA3gKCvqAawWQBMB+ALigHIBjRFYGgGjwIHoOiTTr7GqFlC5QA7gHsAToQDOUAEYRgwCFKgIAZlGQTkAWglhgCPQEM47fJuTUAFAFcwpM6tIBJUrOqzgUkgDmANoAugCUGAB8UABuEgikOAC+ANw4OKCQUADKajFqGNhWPGT8snlqrMU29uVwEHQmegAyCL6ePn6BEejRcQnJaRng0AAqABaBhfBIqFAAPjkVUkOZ0ABiyIUTgUE0NjQhQ5oOyI2mWwCyIDASALZgekx2YFJG3lA7yAERuARQdD0viK-3+xDIhQEs2YbFBnG44NIwi0Oj0hmMFwsxX+NmKSUKr3eQ3+KLsiIw6EwUKYNBEACoFotyZTMKdSBBNCQIKQoHSOL9sQRCWBZAA6Gx2PbjCAgQ5hNJw-CiCyyCRQMxbNRvKSUQVK7gSqUyuV4qAQODlEGK4ViiU0SY0MJ6kTcFVqjVmqTa3WKl1QO3S2VO-5JZJAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an implementation detail in TS. Types are not narrowed when you are storing the value in a different variable. The same issue exists for the square bracket notation. You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616994/typescript-type-narrowing-not-working-for-in-when-key-is-stored-in-a-variable), it deals with a similar issue. Apparently, this is done for compiler performance.

You can fix your issue by using both `props.fn` and `props.kind`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSwgO2FAvFA3gKCvqAawWQBMB+ALigHIBjRFYGgGjwIHoOiTTr7GqFlC5QA7gHsAToQDOUAEYRgwCFKgIAZlGQTkAWglhgCPQEM47fJuTUAFAFcwpM6tIBJUrOqzgUkgDmANoAugCUGAB8UABuEgikOAC+ANw4OKCQUADKajFqGNhWPGT8snlqrMU29uVwEHQmegAyCL6ePn6BEejRcQnJaRng0AAqABaBhfBIqFAAPjkVUkOZ0ABiyIUTgUE0NjQhQ5oOyI2mWwCyIDASALZgekx2YFJG3lA7yAERuARQdD0viK-3+xDIhQEs2YbFBnG44NIwi0Oj0hmMFwsxX+NmKSUKr3eQ3+KJebzAsgAdIiMOhMFCmDQoL9sQRCRTKTY7HtxhAQIcwmk4fhRBZZBIoGYtmo3lJKKyRdwuTy+QK8VAIHByhptGT3tTeLT6eUpPkpDQWcKoOyqVyaJMLQqRNwxRKpRqpLL5VbRHbefywnjkkA)

Or write a type guard function.

Comment: Or you could just check if `props.kind` is `"server"` since it's not optional: https://tsplay.dev/WJ5j6m

Comment: And also, they actually are narrowed here: https://tsplay.dev/wjQg6W, but only when the discriminant property is always required. TS is every bit of quirky as JS is.

Comment: Thanks @nullptr. Link and details of the behavior are much appreciated. More or less what I figured. As for using `props.fn` and `props.kind`, I will likely end up using a type assertion to force `fn` down the proper path. Since these types will ultimately end up in a React component, I need to be somewhat careful about referencing the whole `props` object to avoid de optimizations